# How to directly download a file from server,without saving it in any folder?

Tags: java, download, client-server, fileoutputstream

```
if(!ErmUtil.isNull(listOfActualFilePaths) && listOfActualFilePaths.size()>0){
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/smiles/wrk/attachments/ermWeb/taxation/testing.zip");
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

    Iterator itrOnFNames = listOfActualFilePaths.iterator();
    while (itrOnFNames.hasNext()) {
        StringBuffer ActualPath = (StringBuffer) itrOnFNames.next();
        addToZipFile(ActualPath.toString(), zos);
    }
    zos.close();//Closing Both Streams
    fos.close();
}

public  void addToZipFile(String fileName, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Writing '" + fileName + "' to zip file");
    File file = new File(fileName);
    int index = fileName.lastIndexOf("/");
    String fileNameForZip =  fileName.substring(index+1);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileNameForZip);
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }
    zos.closeEntry();
    fis.close();
}
```

I am using above code, to save zip-ed file on a specific location. But what i want to do is that, instead of saving that file, it get downloaded directly.

**Edit 1**
See If I want to download a zip file,then according to above code, on path /smiles/wrk/attachments/ermWeb/taxation/testing.zip it will be saved first,then from that folder, I(server) can send it to client(Computer).

But I don't want to save it on the specified path,Instead of "saving first to folder and then sending to client",  I directly want to send it to client.

Comment: What? What?? What???

Comment: so u want to download something without saving the file. hw abt u download ,save then delete?

Comment: If you download something, it WILL be saved somewhere in your computer, no exceptions, no buts. If you don't want it to remain in your computer after you have used it, simply remove it.

Comment: No No No...see If I want to download a zip file,then according to above code, on path /smiles/wrk/attachments/ermWeb/taxation/testing.zip it will be saved first,then from that folder, I(server) can send it to client(Computer).I don't want to save it on the specified path, I directly want to send it to client.

Comment: You may write to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to hold the contents temporary in memory.

Comment: @RishiPrakash-It depends on how are you accessing client and which one is your server. There seems to have a 3-way ccommunication as you didn't specify which one is server?

Comment: Make your mind: *"without saving it in any folder*" and *"it will be saved first"*...

Comment: @m0skit0 without saving it in anyfolder :) exactly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP is making fun of the valuable time of the professionals by asking absurd question which doesn't have a proper meaning and also,`he is changing his requirement from time to time`!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman Please consider OP is not well versed in how big geeks like shekhar suman ask questions on Stackoverflow, on the same time he wants genuine help on this topic.

Comment: @RishiPrakash-Neither I am a `big-geek`,NOR I will consider this again as it's totally absurd question with no meaning...

Comment: @RishiPrakash- I even edited your question to make others understand what you're trying to achieve! BUt,`All in VAIN`!

Comment: @shekharsuman Nobody is forced to read this question, waste time on it, or answer it. I don't understand the requirement so I simply walk away. Have a nice day!

Comment: According to your textual description you want to do a server-client transfer but there is not the slightest piece of network code seen in your code examples. Actually, the requirement is trivial to solve: nobody forces you to pass a `FileOutputStream` to the constructor of `ZipOutputStream`, it can be any `OutputStream` you like, e.g. the output stream of a network socket so you would send the zipped data directly without any detour. However, since your networking code is missing, there is no way of giving further directions.

Comment: @Holger No, actually I failed to explain my problem properly, So I am working on it on my Own. I will post the solution here. Thank for you concern. :)